# NullPointerException after starting an Activity (at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:78))

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm scratching my head on this one, not sure what to make of it. I received a report of a NullPointerException happening after I started the activity, but not all the time. Any ideas what might be happening?

Here's the stack trace, as reported by Google. Note that onItemClick() called startIntent, and somewhere there is where the NullPointerException happened.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:78)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4180)
at com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.al.onItemClick(Unknown Source)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3480)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4823)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's the code.

```
public MainNavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragMan,int locLogActivity) {
    mContext=context;
    mFragMan=fragMan;
    mTitle=context.getString(locLogActivity);
    mHashMap=new HashMap<String,Class<?>>();
    addToMap(R.string.upgrade_activity,ManageAddOnPurchaseActivity.class);
    addToMap(R.string.qth_map_activity,QthMapActivity.class);
    addToMap(R.string.export_to_adif,WriteADIF.class);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context,R.layout.drawer_list_item);
    for (String key:mHashMap.keySet()) {
        mAdapter.add(key);
    }
}

private void addToMap(int titleResource, Class<?> theClass) {
    String title=mContext.getString(titleResource);
    if (!mTitle.equals(title)) {
        mHashMap.put(title,theClass);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,mHashMap.get(((TextView)view).getText()));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NPE seems to come from the second parameter of your `Intent`, which is `null`.

This is caused by a `null`value returned by your `HashMap` because the key that you access with `getText()` has no associated value, or is associated with `null`.

What is the `view` you click on? Ensure you put the text of that view in your `HashMap`.

**UPDATE:** Maybe the problem happens when you click on the list header. Check if you have a header.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Indeed your code looks fine. Maybe your list has a header? Do you manage to reproduce the bug when you click on something particular?